# For loop is incrementing 'i' before internal code execution is complete

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have 4 console.logs during the execution of the code inside of this for loop.

```js
for(i=0;i<selectorStrArr.length;i++){
    console.log(i)
    const selectorStr = selectorStrArr[i]

    const selectorNameProps = this.splitNameProps(selectorStr)
    console.log(i)
    const selectorNameArr = selectorNameProps.nameArr

    const selectorProps = this.getProps(selectorNameProps.propsStr)
    console.log(i)
    for(n=0;n<selectorNameArr.length;n++){
        //to account for multiple selectors on a style object
        const name = selectorNameArr[n]
        if(!selectorObj[name])
            selectorObj[name] = {}

        Object.assign(selectorObj[name], selectorProps)
        //if for some reason class appears twice
        //assign rather than overwrite
    }
    console.log(i)
}
```

the console reads as follows

```
0
1
2
2
```

the for loop is being cut short because 'i' is being incremented during the execution of the inner code. I've never seen this happen before and as you can see, nothing inside of the inner code is altering the value of 'i'. Does anyone know what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Kindly also, include what is `this` (include the class). `selcetorstrArr`, and other related variables which are used but they have not any information in question.

Comment: chances are `splitNameProps` and `getProps` are also using a global `i` - never use globals unless 110% necessary

Answer (score 1):

please declare your `i` variable like below

```
for(let i=0;i<selectorStrArr.length;i++) {//}
```

local variable.

and if you want to have access to `i` in `this.splitNameProps` please pass extra param. like bleow

`this.splitNameProps(selectorStr, i)`

Comment: You're saying when i is declared without let, it's within the scope of other called functions? You've got to be shitting me.... lol

Comment: Yeah, thank you. That's crazy. I had no idea.